# How do I get jQuery to call REST service without getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when I have no access to the server?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to query a RESTful service that returns XML, using jQuery.  I have no access to the server, so I can't change the output or headers it is providing.

The response I am receiving is xml, but of course I'm getting a cross-site scripting error.

To get around this, I tried using jsonp, but since the format I'm receiving is xml, that also errors: (Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/xml.).

I do see the xml response in the Content using the Safari Web Inspector, so is there a way I can prevent this error and carry on with using the xml?

I hope that makes sense.  For reference, here is the code I have tried:

First is the original ajax query resulting in the error: *XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://the-rest-url/xxx. Origin http://127.0.0.1:8020 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin* (it's localhost as I'm using it on my PC to develop -- I also tried deploying to a web server).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://the-rest-url/xxx',
    success: function() {alert("success");},
    error: function() {alert("error")}
});
```

Next is the jsonp attempt which returns the xml, but causes the *Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/xml.* error.  I also tried it with dataType: "jsonp text" and other variations...

```
     $.ajax({
      url: 'https://the-rest-url/xxx',
      success: function() {alert("success");},
      error: function() {alert("error")},
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonp: "jsonpCallback"
});
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a reliable workaround for client side cross domain requests except JSONP. Although jQuery can receive [JSONP responses](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in formats other than JSON since version 1.5 that response has to be JSONP compatible, namely being wraped in the callback supplied. In your case you probably have no choice but to implement a server side wrapper ([here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) is an example for PHP) for the data you want to request so that it seems to be coming from the same domain.

Comment: Thankyou.  Although I suspected it, I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer ;)  Ultimately though, I want to put this into a Google Gadget, so I wouldn't be able to use a server side wrapper would I?  Or is there another way entirely with Google Gadgets?  Thanks again.

Comment: Well nothing prevents you from creating a wrapper that returns JSONP.